# identify increase in value in a sequence and revert it based on condition R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, sequence

I am working with a sequence of entries that occurred over a span of days. A slice of the data for a given id essentially looks like something below. Where there is an increase in event_order number and the type_of_event in the same row is 6 or 7 or 8, I would like the value in the event_order column to remain as the previous (e.g. if there is an event_order increase from 2 to 3 but the type_of_event is 7, then change the 3 back to 2).

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
event_order <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4)
type_of_event <- c(0,1,3,4,0,0,6,7,7,7,8,7,7,7,8,8)

df <- data.frame(id, event_order, type_of_event)
df

id        event_order    type_of_event
1          1              0
1          1              1
1          1              3
1          1              4
1          2              0
1          2              0
1          2              6
1          2              7
1          3              7    <--
1          3              7
1          3              8
1          3              7
1          3              7
1          4              7    <--
1          4              8
1          4              8
```

The desired output is below. The change that occurs is in the event_order column.

```
id        event_order    type_of_event
1          1              0
1          1              1
1          1              3
1          1              4
1          2              0
1          2              0
1          2              6
1          2              7
1          2              7   
1          2              7
1          2              8
1          2              7
1          2              7
1          2              7
1          2              8
1          2              8
```

I was searching for a similar q/a to my specific problem, but I was unable to come to a conclusion. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Edit: When I try the following code provided

```
df[df$type_of_event %in% c(6:8),]$event_order <- head(df[df$type_of_event %in% c(6:8), ]$event_order, 1)
```

The code works for the example data I gave. However, I don't want the first value of event_order to be applied, but rather the most recent (this may not have been clear in my initial wording). Below is an example of an instance in the data where the code does not necessarily provide the desired output.

Data:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
event_order <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4)
type_of_event <- c(0,1,3,4,0,0,6,4,0,7,8,7,7,7,8,8)

df <- data.frame(id, event_order, type_of_event)
df

  id        event_order    type_of_event
    1          1              0
    1          1              1
    1          1              3
    1          1              4
    1          2              0
    1          2              0
    1          2              6
    1          2              4
    1          3              0    <-- changed to non-6/7/8 value
    1          3              7
    1          3              8
    1          3              7
    1          3              7
    1          4              7    <--
    1          4              8
    1          4              8
```

When I apply the code, the following occurs:

```
id        event_order    type_of_event
        1          1              0
        1          1              1
        1          1              3
        1          1              4
        1          2              0
        1          2              0
        1          2              6
        1          2              4
        1          3              0    <--
        1          2              7
        1          2              8
        1          2              7
        1          2              7
        1          2              7    
        1          2              8
        1          2              8
```

This is the desired output:

```
id        event_order    type_of_event
        1          1              0
        1          1              1
        1          1              3
        1          1              4
        1          2              0
        1          2              0
        1          2              6
        1          2              4
        1          3              0    
        1          3              7
        1          3              8
        1          3              7
        1          3              7
        1          3              7    
        1          3              8
        1          3              8
```

Comment: What is the logic behind `event_order`? When does it increase?

Comment: I am not sure if it matters overall - its just based on consecutive entries. Eg. if there are entries logged on Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri it is 1,1,1,1 and then if next entry occurs on Sat it is 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible base R solution.
First create a binary variable telling where in `event_order` there is a change. Then use it as a logical index and get the values in `type_of_event` satisfying the condition (to be 6, 7 or 8). And assign the entire segment of `event_order` to the previous one in case there's a match.

```
d <- c(1, diff(df$event_order))
inx <- which(df$type_of_event[as.logical(d)] %in% 6:7)
sp <- split(df$event_order, df$event_order)
for(i in inx){
  if(i > 1L){
    sp[[i]] <- sp[[i - 1]]
  }
}
df$event_order <- unlist(sp)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? Applying the first value of `event_order` when `type_of_event` is 6, 7 or 8.

```r
df[df$type_of_event %in% c(6:8),]$event_order <- head(df[df$type_of_event %in% c(6:8), ]$event_order, 1)

   id event_order type_of_event
1   1           1             0
2   1           1             1
3   1           1             3
4   1           1             4
5   1           2             0
6   1           2             0
7   1           2             6
8   1           2             7
9   1           2             7
10  1           2             7
11  1           2             8
12  1           2             7
13  1           2             7
14  1           2             7
15  1           2             8
16  1           2             8
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I clarified what I am looking for in my original post and what did not work when I tried this code.

Comment: So far, you could do `mutate(df, event_order = cumsum(type_of_event == 0 & lead(type_of_event != 0)))` to construct `event_order`, is it close to what you want?

Comment: This won't work if more ID's are added. The event order just keeps growing instead of restarting according to the id. The initial code that was given was a bit closer to what I wanted but still not exact.

Comment: Then you could `group_by` id. So `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(df, event_order = cumsum(type_of_event == 0 & lead(type_of_event != 0)))`